# What's the syntax of the following in c?

Tags: c

```
fd1 = open("/dev/test_kft" "1",00);
```

What does `"/dev/test_kft" "1"` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explicit form in C is this:

```
char part1[] = "/dev/test_kft";
char part2[] = "1";
char path[strlen(part1) + strlen(part2) + 1];
strcpy(path, part1);
strcat(path, part2);
```

This still does not replicate the fact that the "implicit" concatenation form is place in the rodata segment. In the example I've given, it'll be on the stack. You could put it on the heap with malloc. The implicit version is done at compile time, and preferred if possible.

Comment: I don't really see how `"one" "two"` isn't explicit though. What's hidden?

Comment: @detly Yeah, this answer is very poor ... it doesn't even touch on the question. The poor OP left SO baffled, never to return.

Comment: @JimBalter if you read the OPs comments on other answers you'll see his original question wasn't very clear. SO doesn't really handle situations like this very well. I answered what appears to be his true question.

Comment: The question was clear and the other two answers addressed it. The confusion comes from the misuse in the answers of "implicit" and "explicit", as @delty noted, and the failure by anyone other than tJener to mention that the concatenation of adjacent strings only applies to literals. Anyway, this question was asked over 4 years ago and I apologize for commenting years later, and won't comment more on it.

Answer (score 10):

It's implicit concatenation as performed by the compiler. It results in `"/dev/test_kft1"`.

Comment: What's the explicit form to concate string in C/c++?

Comment: you can use strcat or strncat function from libc library

Answer (score 4):

The preprocessor concatenates adjacent string literals, so that line is the same as

`fd1 = open("/dev/test_kft1", 00);`

Comment: What's the **explicit** form to concate string in C/c++?